# Prefer more resources on Windows HPC?

Tags: azure, hpc

If I specify a min/max core or socket counts, is there a way to tell HPC to prefer to use more resources? i.e. if I have the below job/task, can I tell HPC to prefer more sockets?

```
<Job Version="3.000" UnitType="Socket" IsExclusive="true" JobType="Batch" JobTemplate="Default" MinSockets="8" MaxSockets="24" Name="testJob">
<Task Version="3.000" UnitType="Socket" GroupId="0" Name="whatever" MinSockets="8" MaxSockets="24" Type="Basic" CommandLine="..." />
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just change `MinSockets` to 24 in that case.  You should be modifying your question, not leaving comments, which have been flagged for removal.